# Using Picasso library in a custom GridView in android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am working on a project where there is a custom gridview containing an image and a textview below it.I am trying to load the images from url using Picasso library.The issue i am facing is this:

**When the images are loaded and i scroll the gridview the images at the bottom of the list it keeps loading.But when i scroll back to the top,the images which have already been loaded start loading again.Why doesnt the images in the top stay fixed?Why do they start loading again?**

My code is shown below:

The adapter in which i am setting the images:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
   ArrayList<Sports_data> list;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
      public CustomGridAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Sports_data> list ) {
          mContext = c;
          this.list=list;
          mInflater= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          imageLoader=new ImageLoader(c);
      }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridHolder holder=null;
        if(convertView==null)
            {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single,parent,false);
            holder=new GridHolder();
            holder.gridimage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.txtgrid=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        else
        {
            holder = (GridHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //holder.gridimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        holder.txtgrid.setText(list.get(position).sports_name);
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(list.get(position).sports_image_url, holder.gridimage);  
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(list.get(position).sports_image_url).noFade().into(holder.gridimage);

        return convertView;
    }

    public class GridHolder
    {
        ImageView gridimage;
        TextView txtgrid;
    }

}
```

This is the line in which i have used Picasso library:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(list.get(position).sports_image_url).noFade().into(holder.gridimage);
```

Please help!!

Comment: What permissions you have in manifest?

Comment: Should i have write external storage permisssion?

Comment: Try adding write and read for external storage.

Comment: @Niko you don't have to add read permission if you adding write permission, because write include read .

Comment: hay @AchuthanM  i am facing the same problem . if you found solution plz post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app, I'm using AsyncTask to load images into GridView and it looks exactly the same way as you described

I think this is a nature of a GridView/ListView to recycle images which are not visible on the screen. If a GridView/ListView didn't do that while scrolling both up and down, the memory allocated to your application would run out very quickly leading to a crash.

The solution for your issue is probably caching loaded (downloaded) images into memory/disk and then using them instead of reloading again.

Please look at the training I followed: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html.

Unfortunately, I skipped the part with caching bitmaps, so I'm not able to provide you with any code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a constructor in your GridHolder class.  In there you need to call **findViewById()** for each view that you want the View Holder to cache.  Do something like this:

```
class GridHolder {
    ImageView gridimage;
    TextView txtgrid;

    public GridHolder(View itemView) {
        gridimage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        txtgrid= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    }
}
```